# In meteor, can pub/sub be used for arbitrary in-memory objects (not mongo collection)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I want to establish a two-way (bidirectional) communication within my meteor app. But I need to do it without using mongo collections.

So can pub/sub be used for arbitrary in-memory objects?

Is there a better, faster, or lower-level way? Performance is my top concern.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, pub/sub can be used for arbitrary objects. [Meteor’s docs even provide an example](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish):

```
// server: publish the current size of a collection
Meteor.publish("counts-by-room", function (roomId) {
  var self = this;
  check(roomId, String);
  var count = 0;
  var initializing = true;

  // observeChanges only returns after the initial `added` callbacks
  // have run. Until then, we don't want to send a lot of
  // `self.changed()` messages - hence tracking the
  // `initializing` state.
  var handle = Messages.find({roomId: roomId}).observeChanges({
    added: function (id) {
      count++;
      if (!initializing)
        self.changed("counts", roomId, {count: count});
    },
    removed: function (id) {
      count--;
      self.changed("counts", roomId, {count: count});
    }
    // don't care about changed
  });

  // Instead, we'll send one `self.added()` message right after
  // observeChanges has returned, and mark the subscription as
  // ready.
  initializing = false;
  self.added("counts", roomId, {count: count});
  self.ready();

  // Stop observing the cursor when client unsubs.
  // Stopping a subscription automatically takes
  // care of sending the client any removed messages.
  self.onStop(function () {
    handle.stop();
  });
});

// client: declare collection to hold count object
Counts = new Mongo.Collection("counts");

// client: subscribe to the count for the current room
Tracker.autorun(function () {
  Meteor.subscribe("counts-by-room", Session.get("roomId"));
});

// client: use the new collection
console.log("Current room has " +
            Counts.findOne(Session.get("roomId")).count +
            " messages.");
```

In this example, `counts-by-room` is publishing an arbitrary object created from data returned from `Messages.find()`, but you could just as easily get your source data elsewhere and publish it in the same way. You just need to provide the same `added` and `removed` callbacks like the example here.

You’ll notice that on the client there’s a collection called `counts`, but this is purely in-memory on the client; it’s not saved in MongoDB. I think this is necessary to use pub/sub.

If you want to avoid even an in-memory-only collection, you should look at `Meteor.call`. You could create a `Meteor.method` like `getCountsByRoom(roomId)` and call it from the client like `Meteor.call('getCountsByRoom', 123)` and the method will execute on the server and return its response. This is more the traditional Ajax way of doing things, and you lose all of Meteor’s reactivity.

Comment: Sorry, I think I messed up on my title. I'm aware of this functionality of pub/sub. I was actually more into the 2 way communication part (esp server to clients). I'll accept as this is the perfect answer. For anyone interested in proper 2 way communication, take a look at meteor-streams. https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-streams

Comment: Thanks, Meteor Streams is a good find. Yeah, perhaps a bit more detail in what you’re trying to achieve would generate more useful and specific answers. If Meteor Streams doesn’t solve your problem I suggest you post a new question rather than editing this one.

Comment: For anyone else looking for answer check out http://meteorcapture.com/publishing-anything/ it made it really easy to understand.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add another easy solution. You can pass `connection: null` to your Collection instantiation on your server. Even though this is not well-documented, but I heard from the meteor folks that this makes the collection in-memory.

Here's an example code posted by Emily Stark a year ago:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Test = new Meteor.Collection("test");
  Meteor.subscribe("testsub");
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Test = new Meteor.Collection("test", { connection: null });
  Meteor.publish("testsub", function () {
    return Test.find();
  });

  Test.insert({ foo: "bar" });
  Test.insert({ foo: "baz" });
}
```

Comment: Also to note, because our current project requires the best performance, we are still sticking with the pure-memory approach (no mongo).

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit

This should go under comment but I found it could be too long for it so I post as an answer. Or perhaps I misunderstood your question?

I wonder why you are against **mongo**. I somehow find it a good match with Meteor.

Anyway, everyone's use case can be different and your idea is doable but not with some serious hacks.

if you look at Meteor source code, you can find `tools/run-mongo.js`, it's where **Meteor** talks to **mongo**, you may tweak or implement your adaptor to work with your in-memory objects.

Another approach I can think of, will be to wrap your in-memory objects and write a database logic/layer to intercept existing **mongo** database communications (default port on 27017), you have to take care of all system environment variables like `MONGO_URL` etc. to make it work properly.

Final approach is wait until **Meteor** officially supports other databases like **Redis**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your input on this. We cannot utilize mongo for our project for many reasons, the most important being that our project requires low latency. Because disk IO is a bottleneck and we don't need persistence, we can safely take out mongodb.

Comment: @Dave fair point. As I said everyone's use case is different, Meteor is a good framework anyhow, all the best :)

Comment: btw, in this case you may really dive into Meteor source code and remove mongodb completely

Comment: Yes, at this point we are trying to balance between stripping and preserving functionalities.