# How to have Meteor.Collection without MongoDB?

Tags: reactjs, meteor

While developing a small project, there is absolutely no need for a MongoDB persistence layer, but I would like the benefit of publishing and subscribing for client synchronization.

From a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455914/in-meteor-can-pub-sub-be-used-for-arbitrary-in-memory-objects-not-mongo-collec), I implemented a very crude interface *(untested)* :

```
// server
const _cache = new Map();

const rooms = {
   registerObserver: (roomHash, observer) => {
      if (!_cache.has(roomHash)) {
         _cache.add(roomHash, { messages:[], observers:[] );
      }

      const room = _cache.get(roomHash);

      room.observers.add(observer);

      observer.added("rooms", roomHash, { messages:room.messages });
      observer.onStop(() => room.observers.delete(observer));
      observer.ready();          
   }
}

Meteor.publish('chatroom', function (roomHash) {
   check(roomHash, String);

   rooms.registerObserver(roomHash, this);
});


Meteor.methods({

   pushMessage: function (roomHash, message) {
      check(roomHash, String);
      check(message, String);

      const room = _cache.get(roomHash);

      room.messages.push(message);
      room.observers.forEach(observer => 
         observer.changed("rooms", roomHash, { messages:room.messags })
      );
   }

});
```

But, now, I need to fetch the `messages` from the given room, so I added :

```
// client, React hook
const useChatMessages = roomHash => {
   const loading = useTracker(() => {
      const handle = Meteor.subscribe("chatroom", roomHash);

      return !handle.ready();
   }, [orderHash]);
   const pushMessage = useCallback(message => {
      Meteor.call('pushMessage', roomHash, message);
   }, [roomHash]);

   const messages = []; // .... ???

   return { loading, messages, pushMessage };
};
```

I have no idea how to fetch the messages. Since I removed the MongoDB dependencies, I do not have access to `Mongo.Colllection`, and it seems like `Meteor.Collection` is also unavailable (i.e. `Meteor.Collection === undefined`)

So, I publish, and also subscribe, but how do I *fetch* the published `messages`?

(**Note:** the above code compiles, but it is mostly untested as explained in the question.)

Comment: To you use Collections you need of the package of Mongo, but you don't need create a real collection on database Mongo. I did a collection declaration, like `new Mongo.Collection("rooms")`, but I never insert data in DB. Then the collection exist in app, but don't in DB. Then I create a publish with the data I want.

Comment: You can see more information in https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html and https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html

Comment: This is the use-case described in the advanced publish example in the documentation. On the client you will not be able to tell the difference. Just subscribe as usual and you will find the document in the collection just like before.